# HttpServletResponse header property encoded incorrecty

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to put data into header. When i add it in latin, it is received on server side correctly. But when I try to add it in chinese, for example `中國的錯誤,` it is received on client as `?????`
How can I set header to be encoded as `UTF-8`?

I tried doing something like this, but it didn't help:

```
servletResponse.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
servletResponse.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Set additionally -Dfile.encoding=utf8 in the string of server startup.